# Bloomberg (in Excel): Get security name from ISIN

Tags: bloomberg

In Excel, I have a list of ISINs for bonds. Now I want to find the ratings for them and use BDP. The problem is how do I get the security name (Bloomberg can work with) from the ISIN? I can do it manually with the spreadsheet builder, but there I have to do this for each individual security. Is it possible to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the Security Name to do your job. Simply place in an excel cell (example B1) this formula (assuming that in cell A1 you have a valid ISIN):

```
= A1 & " Corp"
```

and then use B1 to obtain your desired data from Bloomberg.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if off the top of your head if this is also possible with equities (using Equity instead of Corp) or more exotic stuff like CLOs?

Comment: @Alex, for equities the ISIN is not the right way (ISIN is not a unique identifier), but you can try to build a ticker in the form: ISIN + "primary market" + Equity. Example, ISIN  + "US Equity" for a us stock

Comment: Thank you. It's not an issue yet, but I'm sure it'll come up in the next months.